# Making a custom drop down list that contains items and an editText android

Tags: java, android, drop-down-menu

I want to make a drop-down list that contains a list of items and an editText to add more items to the menu

the items contains text and a checkList

my question is what is the best method (Java) I can follow to make that possible

a visualization of what I want to make would look something like this

[image: custom drop down list]

Comment: You've to customise...  Android not providing that kind of options

Comment: @GobuCSG Okay in that case what is the best option do I have? Like I'm thinking an alert dialog could make this work but I'm not sure, and I don't know if there is a better option?!

Comment: You can do  using dialog with recyclerview